# rotate a point in a 2d grid with 2 different measure units

Tags: python

I am in a situation that I need rotate a set of points (hexagons) in a grid system that uses arbitrary non-related length measures.
The data available related to the axis system is just a percentage, so X/Y = 1/2.
I have no option of resizing or change the axis units.
When I apply that rotation equation:
ox, oy = origin
px, py = point

```
qx = ox + math.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - math.sin(angle) * (py - oy)
qy = oy + math.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + math.cos(angle) * (py - oy)
return qx, qy
```

The rotating hexagons are unsurprisingly distorted along the rotation angle.
My question is what is the "correction factor" I should add to the rotation equation, to cancel the distortion.

[rotating from 0 to 90 produce axis stretch][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1KCl.gif

Comment: @Damir Tenishev; The problem with dividing on 2, is it shrunk the y axis at a fixed rate with rotation changes, while we need to correct it interactively in accordance with the change in angle rotation. That brings the next question which is how to map a 360 degree rotation to values according to  the following order:    degree: 0 - 90 -180 - 270   to  Values: 1 -  2 - 1 - 2

Answer (score 0):

Everything is just fine with the formula here. By some aside reason it is stretched (squeezed by X axis or extended by Y axe). I would recommend to find the root cause in your program (drawing context, etc.).
Otherwise you may correct your code to:

```
qx = ox + math.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - math.sin(angle) * (py - oy)
qy = oy + (math.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + math.cos(angle) * (py - oy))/2.0;
return qx, qy
```